# singularities $\mathcal{A}_{g,d}$ in positive characteristic

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi,

I would like to understand the singularities of the moduli spaces of abelian varieties with polarization of degree $d>1$ in characteristic $p>0$ when $p|d$. Do you know some good references?

Thanks

Comment: Jeff Achter's thesis might be useful to you. You can find it here: http://www.math.upenn.edu/~chai/theses/jeff_thesis.pdf

